# Object exist, object change value JS, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my application start this JSonResult doesn`t exist and when I would like to use this (I get error "TypeError")

```
var newImg = $.parseJSON($("#UploadTarget").contents().find("#jsonResult")[0].innerHTML);
```

What I would like to do? I would like to have event which will tell me this object exist or this object change value.

```
 var newImg = $.parseJSON($("#UploadTarget").contents().find("#jsonResult")[0].innerHTML);
```

How should I write this?

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace pol
    {
        public class WrappedJsonResult : JsonResult
        {
            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<html><body><textarea id=\"jsonResult\" name=\"jsonResult\">");
                base.ExecuteResult(context);
                context.HttpContext.Response.Write("</textarea></body></html>");
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click button Image is upload to server but Result never opent important method UploadImage_Complete();

```
@model po.Models.Stwna
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "StronaGlowna", FormMethod.Post,
                                         new
                                             {
                                                 enctype = "multipart/form-data",
                                                 id = "ImgForm",
                                                 name = "ImgForm",
                                                 target = "UploadTarget"
                                             }))
{
    <input type="file" name="imageFile" />

    <input type="button" class="button" value="@Model.ZO" onclick="UploadImage()" />
}
<iframe id="UploadTarget" name="UploadTarget" onload="UploadImage_Complete();" style="position: absolute;
    left: -999em; top: -999em;"></iframe>
<div id="Images">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isFirstLoad = true;

    function UploadImage() {
        $("#ImgForm").submit();
    }
    function UploadImage_Complete() {
        //Check to see if this is the first load of the iFrame
        if (isFirstLoad == true) {
            isFirstLoad = false;
            return;
        }

        //Reset the image form so the file won't get uploaded again
        document.getElementById("ImgForm").reset();

        //Grab the content of the textarea we named jsonResult .  This shold be loaded into
        //the hidden iFrame.
        var newImg = $.parseJSON($("#UploadTarget").contents().find("#jsonResult")[0].innerHTML);

        //If there was an error, display it to the user
        if (newImg.IsValid == false) {
            alert(newImg.Message);
            return;
        }



        //Create a new image and insert it into the Images div.  Just to be fancy,
        //we're going to use a "FadeIn" effect from jQuery
        var imgDiv = document.getElementById("Images");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = newImg.ImagePath;

        //Hide the image before adding to the DOM
        $(img).hide();
        imgDiv.appendChild(img);
        //Now fade the image in
        $(img).fadeIn(500, null);


       // $('#Images').text(newImg.ImagePath);
    }
</script>
```

MVC

```
[HttpPost]
        public WrappedJsonResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileWrapper imageFile)
        {

            return new WrappedJsonResult
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    IsValid = true,
                    Message = string.Empty,
                    ImagePath = Url.Content(String.Format("http://a1.ec-images.myspacecdn.com/images01/29/4982945eb42646efafe2f94855ac3d21/l.jpg"))

                }
            };
        }
```

I get this image when I click button twice but when I click once I don`t get any result.

Comment: What populates `#jsonResult`?

Comment: @plalx I added to my post rest impotant things

Comment: Have you waited until the DOM is ready before tyring to manipulate the  `textarea`? Try this `$(function () { alert($.parseJSON($('#jsonResult').val())); });`

Comment: @plalx this will not help me because this object is create when picture is upload into server. And all things I make on popup.

Comment: Give us more information about the textarea's population process and we should be able to help you, but as it is we do not have enough information.

Comment: @plalx I need information when jsonResult is created and also when value of this object is changed. (you know some times if file have got 6MB you have to wait longer to get result)

Comment: @plalx I edited post. This code work fine if you are not make form into popup but I would like to do this on popup. I have to click twice to get image on website because when I click first time this doesn`t work  onload="UploadImage_Complete();" but JSON send result

Comment: and this show why I need event to get information when JSON is creted or change result to do this method UploadImage_Complete();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide use Timer to make this [Simple Timer](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/)